# VS Code Workspace: Select Specific Files to View

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently discovered VS Code workspaces and use them to target specific sections of my app like this:

```json
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "name": " Dashboard ",
      "path": "lib/dashboard",
    },
    {
      "name": " Flights",
      "path": "lib/flights",
    },
}
```

This works great. But I'd like to add another one that shows me a list of specific files. Something like this:

```json
{
  "folders": [
    ...
    {
      "name": "Database Models",
      "paths": [
        "lib/model_dashboard.dart", 
        "lib/model_flights.dart"
      ]
    },
}
```

So then when I open `Database Models` I can have a consolidated view of all my model files spread throughout my app.

Is this possible in a VS Code workspace?

Comment: Multi Root Workspace does not support virtual folders like VS Solution Explorer, you can use [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links) and create a file with file paths and show them in a View in the Explorer Bar

Comment: there is [Solution Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fernandoescolar.vscode-solution-explorer) like extension for VSC, maybe you can use that

Comment: and what paths would you like those files you list to be under? same relative path as specified? (what if some relative paths are to parent directories?) all files placed directly under one "virtual directory" (what if there are name conflicts?) some other more complex mapping logic?

Comment: Yeah, the files are scattered throughout my project next to the pieces of the UI they pertain to. But it would be nice to view them all together in a list because they contain similar functionality. I essentially want to cherry-pick files and have them conveniently listed together.